# Split a big size string from a xml query on "&#xD;" with java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split a big size of string in java. It worked fine on an other string, but the problem is when I try to split this big size string, only some part of the string get splitted. The other part is still the same and not getting splitted.

What I've done so far: I'm using `split()` function, and it doesnt work. Second I use split based on regex `("[\\\\r\\\\n]+")` and put in on arraylist and try to replace from there, and it also doesn't work

my first code:

```
String string;
string = AudioSpectrumProjectionType().trim();

String[] hasil = string.split("&#xD;");
for(int i = 0 ; i<hasil.length;i++){
    System.out.print(hasil[i].trim().replace(" ",","));
    if (i%20 == 0)
       System.out.print("\n");
    if(i != hasil.length-1)
       System.out.print(",");
}
```

my second code:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String string;
string = AudioSpectrumProjectionType().trim();
String[] hasil = string.split("[\\r\\n]+");
for(int i = 0 ; i<hasil.length;i++){
    arrayList.add(hasil[i].trim());
}

for(int i = 0 ; i<arrayList.size();i++){
    String print = arrayList.get(i);
    System.out.println(print.replaceAll("&#xD;",""));
}
```

AudioSpectrumProjectionType() function is just a query from a xml, here is the code:

```
private static String AudioSpectrumProjectionType() throws BaseXException{

    String query =
            "declare default element namespace \"urn:mpeg:mpeg7:schema:2001\";" +
                    "declare namespace mpeg7 = \"urn:mpeg:mpeg7:schema:2001\";" +
                    "declare namespace xsi = \"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\";" +
                    "for $x in doc(\"C:/Users/ponighzwa/IdeaProjects/ExtractDescriptor/cover/lagu/voice isolation 2/xml/original/perempuan/The One That Got Away.xml\")/Mpeg7/Description/MultimediaContent/Audio/AudioDescriptor\n return if($x/@xsi:type=\"AudioSpectrumProjectionType\")then data($x/SeriesOfVector/Raw) else \"\"";

    System.out.println(new XQuery(query).execute(context));
    String hasil = new XQuery(query).execute(context);
    return hasil;
}
```

the result i expect like :

```
0.6324845 0.48125452 0.2834291 0.51651007 0.47841766 0.36249334 0.3128651
```

result i get :

```
769.31354 -0.991627 -0.008771153 -0.0958663 0.047845073 -0.02021278 -0.03738797 0.012309733 0.0136948135&#xD;
2615.384 -0.99431473 0.024853256 -0.07093173 0.0330488 -0.03610177 -0.03400125 0.014497152 0.0082630105&#xD;
2615.384 -0.99431473 0.024853256 -0.07093173 0.0330488 -0.03610177 -0.03400125 0.014497152 0.0082630105&#xD;
2615.384 -0.99431473 0.024853256 -0.07093173 0.0330488 -0.03610177 -0.03400125 0.014497152 0.0082630105            
2615.384 -0.99431473 0.024853256 -0.07093173 0.0330488 -0.03610177 -0.03400125 0.014497152 0.0082630105
2615.384 -0.99431473 0.024853256 -0.07093173 0.0330488 -0.03610177 -0.03400125 0.014497152 0.0082630105
```

I need it without "", anyone ever encounter same problem?

Comment: It's looks is not split, instead it is that  your string have different separator. Maybe only the first half part have '&#xD;' as line separator. So you have to replace the '&#xD;' with "\r\n" first, than split on "[\\r\\n]+".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
split("\\&#xD;");
```

Then the first solution works.

The reason being that in a regular expression `&` is an AND operator.

What is replaced is the numer SGML (HTML) entity for `\r` - a bit strange choice.
Furthermore you might like to do `System.out.println()` instead of `print('\n')` (or it was intentional Unix style line ending).